# Recursive loop for password checking in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, recursion, passwords

OK, I am trying to write a simple object that will contain two strings, one a "user password" and one a "target password," this would be needed if you wanted to script a password change on a remote server using sudo (the first password would be to perform the sudo command, the "target password" would be the string to which the password should be reset.

I want the user to be prompted once for the first password, and then the user will have five tries to enter a second password string and repeat it accurately.   What I came up with, the code below, does not seem to work.  Any ideas?

```
require 'pp' 
require 'RubyGems'
require 'highline/import'  #gem install highline

class Authorization

attr_reader :user_password , :target_password

 pass_code = lambda {
 first_attempt = ask("Enter target password:  "){ |q| q.echo = '*' }
 second_attempt = ask("Re-enter password to verify"){ |q| q.echo = '*'}
}

 ### So we need some sort of recursive loop

def initialize(target_pass=false)
@user_password = ask("Enter your admin password:  ") { |q| q.echo = '*' }

if target_pass
  count = 1
  while n < 6
  pass_code

      if first_attempt == second_attempt
        @target_password =  first_attempt
        return
      else
        count += 1  
      end
    end
  end 

    end
  end

   my_pass = Authorization.new(true)

   pp "pass" , my_pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several problems

- It's `require "rubygems"` (not RubyGems)
- Also, if using Ruby 1.9, loading rubygems isn't necessary.
- The lambda has locally scoped variables assigned that aren't available in the constructor
- The lambda definition itself is out of scope for access anyway
- The loop never terminates (btw, this isn't recursion).

Try something like this instead.

```
require "highline/import"

class Authorization
  attr_accessor :user_password, :target_password

  def prompt(prompt_for_target = false)
    self.user_password = ask_for_password("Enter your admin password")
    return unless prompt_for_target

    5.times do
      password     = ask_for_password("Enter target password")
      confirmation = ask_for_password("Re-enter password to verify")

      if password == confirmation
        self.target_password = password
        return
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def ask_for_password(message)
    ask("#{message}: ") { |q| q.echo = '*' }
  end
end

auth = Authorization.new
auth.prompt(true)

puts auth.user_password
puts auth.target_password
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straightforward and similar to Ryan's solution:

```
require 'highline/import'  #gem install highline

class Authorization

  attr_reader :admin_password, :target_password

  def initialize
    @admin_password = ask_for_password("Enter your admin password: ")
    5.times do
      @target_password = ask_for_password("Enter target password: ")
      verify_target_pass = ask_for_password("Re-enter password to verify: ")
      break if @target_password == verify_target_pass
      @target_password = nil
    end

  end 

  private

  def ask_for_password(message)
    ask(message) {|q| q.echo = "*"}
  end

end

my_pass = Authorization.new
puts "Administrator's password is: #{my_pass.admin_password}"
puts "Target password is: #{my_pass.target_password}"
```

Answer (score 1):

First, thank you all for your answers.  This was my first question, and, unfortunately, came out a little garbled, but all of you seemed to understand it really well.

IMHO, what I was trying to do recursion, but I am not sure that this is the best place for that discussion.

I am using Ruby 1.8.7, which I probably should have mentioned at the beginning of the post.  Ryan's solution worked, but only when I took out the references to "self" and substituted in the instance variable:

```
@user_password = ask_for_password("Enter your admin password") #instead of
self.user_password = ask_for_password("Enter your admin password")
```

this might not be necessary for Ruby 1.9, but it does have the advantage of making prostosuper's almost identical to Ryan's.

Once again, thank you all!  This has been a great "getting my feet wet" experience.

Answer (score 0):

First, this isn't [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion). This is [iteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration). A recursive function would call itself again:

```
def factorial(n)
    if (n == 0)
        1
    else
        n * factorial(n-1)
    end
end
```

Now, for the specific problem you've got; you are trying to loop with the condition:

> ```
> while n < 6
> ```

But note that in the body of your loop, you're doing nothing to change the value of `n`. So your loop cannot terminate. (Further, since you've forgotten to assign a value to `n` in the first place, it probably cannot *start*, either. :)